# How to "Link All" dynamic and/or static libraries, using a folder path and cmake?

Tags: c++, macos, build, cmake, devops

**In my test project I have a folder structure of the following**

```
-Root/
 -Lib_so/   //folder where it contains all of the .so file
 -Lib_a/    //folder where it contains all of the .a file
 -Lib_dll/  //folder where it contains all of the dll file
 -Includes/ //folder where it contains all of the header files
 -main.cpp
```

**I want to write a CMakeLists.txt that generates a single executable that:**

1. automatically link ALL of the .so , .a, and/or dll files just by the folder path shown above.
2. link installed binaries (such as the GLFW installed by brew on mac)

**I have tried the following**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(FirstOpenGL)
set(SOURCE main.cpp)
add_executable(myapp ${SOURCE})

#Below Im trying to link ALL of the libs under the "project's local path"
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Includes)
link_directories(LinkPathSo  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Lib_so)
link_directories(LinkPathA   ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Lib_a)
link_directories(LinkPathDll ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Lib_dll)

target_link_libraries(myapp LinkPathSo)
target_link_libraries(myapp LinkPathA)  
target_link_libraries(myapp LinkPathDll)  


# Below: Im trying to link the installed binaries on mac
find_package(glfw3 3.2 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

target_include_directories(myapp ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(myapp ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(myapp ${OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY})
```

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Only one question at a time

Comment: @TDK ok~ I have remove the extra question :)